# How can MediaFire afford unlimited storage space and bandwidth?

Tags: bandwidth, files, media, online-storage

How can MediaFire (and other online storage websites) afford to offer unlimited storage space, as well as unlimited bandwidth?

Comment: In many ways it works the same as the all you can eat buffets.

Comment: @Zoredache You say that, but I've seen some people get through a dozen or more plates at a time at one of those places! :O

Comment: @Zoredache -- I love the analogy lol. It makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

I gather that they basically work on the principal that:

1. Nobody will use 100% of their storage
2. Nobody will use 100% of their bandwidth.

They're basically taking a gamble on the above statements..

A lot of their bandwidth will be provided with interesting peering arrangements, as well as a few transit providers.

Storage is also cheap, and becoming cheaper, as long as speed and performance isn't a real problem.  Caching data will help alleviate any real disk slowness, so it's not as noticable that they're using 5400 rpm disks, not FC connected disk arrays.

Comment: Which is the same principal that gmail uses with its (currently) 7.4gb of space offered

Comment: They also store the user uploaded data for a period of time before erasing it to make space for new user data.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense -- just like the all-you-can-eat buffet analogy. Thanks.